# Not Getting the Desired value using json.dumps with Python

Tags: python, json

I am Trying to make a small code which will take values from excel and make a json file . I get the desired output except 1 issue . Below is my Code

```
import json
from openpyxl import load_workbook
print("")
path = "output.xlsx"
wb=load_workbook(path)
Sheet1 = wb.active
max_row=Sheet1.max_row
max_column=Sheet1.max_column
for i in range(2, max_column+1):
    listing = []
    for j in range(2, max_row+1):
         dictonery =  {}
         dictonery["ParameterKey"] = (Sheet1.cell(j,1)).value
         dictonery["ParameterValue"] = (Sheet1.cell(j,i)).value
         listing.append(dictonery)     

    print(json.dumps(listing,indent = 4, sort_keys=True))
```

output i am getting for print(listing):

```
print(listing)

[{'ParameterKey': 'SGSSNTCode', 'ParameterValue': 'test'}, {'ParameterKey': 'SDSSCustomer', 'ParameterValue': 'testcompany'}, {'ParameterKey': 'OSName', 'ParameterValue': 'Ubuntu 18.04 LTS'}, {'ParameterKey': 'Hostname', 'ParameterValue': 'testhostname'}, {'ParameterKey': 'SubnetId', 'ParameterValue': 'subnet-0b33e'}, {'ParameterKey': 'SecurityGroupIds', 'ParameterValue': 'sg-05c21ea8,sg-063a770507,sg-0c259b8d,sg-026e2d7b5a'}, {'ParameterKey': 'InstanceType', 'ParameterValue': 'm5.large'}, {'ParameterKey': 'KeyPairName', 'ParameterValue': 'TestPair'}, {'ParameterKey': 'RootVolumeSize', 'ParameterValue': '""'}]
```

Till here everything is good
As you see above The last ParameterValue is "" but
But when i run the last line i.e print(json.dumps(listing,indent = 4, sort_keys=True))
the last ParameterValue i am getting "\"\"" (Below Output)
Below is the output of print(json.dumps(listing,indent = 4, sort_keys=True))

```
print(json.dumps(listing,indent = 4, sort_keys=True))

[
    {
        "ParameterKey": "SGASSNTCode",
        "ParameterValue": "test"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "SGASCustomer",
        "ParameterValue": "testcompany"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "OSName",
        "ParameterValue": "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "Hostname",
        "ParameterValue": "testhostname"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "SubnetId",
        "ParameterValue": "subnet-0b33e"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "SecurityGroupIds",
        "ParameterValue": "sg-05c21ea8,sg-063a770507,sg-0c259b8d,sg-026e2d7b5a"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "InstanceType",
        "ParameterValue": "m5.large"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "KeyPairName",
        "ParameterValue": "TestPair"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "RootVolumeSize",
        "ParameterValue": "\"\""
    }
]
```

The JSON Output i need is with last ParamterValue as "" only . can some please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1 :

Store the value of `json.dumps()` in some variable. Now `.dumps()` returns a string so you can replace the escape char with quotes to just quotes and then write the variable to file.

Method 2 :

When you are populating the variable `dictionery`, if you find the value to be `""` just write `""` in the value. Do not write `""` inside single quotes like you are doing `('""')`. You will have to put a check for this but will work.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.dumps()` converts all the key, values into string while jsonifying.
To convert `""` to string it has to include escape character `\` before them.

You can get back the original value once you load the JSON back with `json.loads()`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. i tried json.loads() and it works but i need to save JSON with "" as last parameter and with particular format like indent = 4 .

Comment: print(json.loads(something,indent = 4, sort_keys=True))
is failing with unexpected keyword argument 'indent'

Comment: `json.loads()` does not take indent as an argument. It just loads the `json object` into a variable with original data type.

Comment: You cannot use `json.loads()` to save your data into some file in `json` format. You need to save `json.dumps()` that you are printing in file. It will be saved with `"/"/""` in the file but when you read the file and then use `json.loads()`, it will get back the original value, i.e.,` ""`.

Comment: Thank-you . my end goal requirement is to save JSON files with last parameter as ""

Comment: I dont need to load the files again in python. i need to use the saved JSON files for other tool

Comment: You should not be worried about the escape characters. On the other tool irrespective of the programming language it may be using, when you decode the json object you should get the actual value, i.e., without escape characters.

Comment: Also if you just want `""` in your output you can take either of 2 methods. Stating in another answer.